# Python tkinter move

Tags: python, tkinter

I have numerous lines on a graph, datalines, horizontal divider line, day and month indicator lines, etc.  I have typically, probably until now, been adding lines in this fashion:

```
canvas_1.create_line(x1,y1,x2,y2)
```

I now have simple problem.  I want to also add in a vertical scale to show how much above and below zero the line is...quite natural.  The datafile is big, roughly 12,000 data units and growing so I have everything setup using the left and right arrow keys to allow scrolling through the data.  It works great but I haven't added in the vertical scale yet.  Right now everything moves:

```
canvas_1.move(ALL,x,y)
```

When I add in the vertical scale I don't want the vertical scale to move.  I know by using the move(ALL) that the vertical scale will also move.

What do I have to change in order to get the vertical scale so it won't move?  Do I have to go out and 'label' all create_line statements???

```
line1 = canvas_1.create_line....
```

If so when I have mega reference of lines that I want to move how do I put them into the move statement.  Do I have to put all the labels into a list or what?  I kinda really lost in the thought process on this concept.

I fess I'm still looking into scrollbars but haven't quite had any good luck with them yet and I have a feeling I will still have the same problem to be dealt with.

Answer (score 0):

The `move` method takes either an id of a single object, or a tag that represents zero or more objects. `ALL` is a built-in tag (literally, the string `"all"`) that refers to everything on the canvas.

So, to use the `move` method without moving the scale, give everything except the scale a unique tag, and then use that tag for the `move` command.

```
canvas_1.create_line(x1,y1,x2,y2, tags=("lines",))
...
canvas_1.move("lines")
```

For more information about tags, see http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#item-specifiers

Comment: Can you use more than tag per move statement or does that trigger you into the x,y of the move statement?  I'm on Windows right now and it doesn't have python installed on it so I can't test right now...sorry.

Comment: @confused: the documentation states it takes only a single tag. What the tkinter docs don't show, but the tcl/tk docs do (upon which tkinter is based - see http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/canvas.htm#M8), is that you can specify logical expressions such as "(tag1||tag2)". So, yes, you can specify more than one tag.